# Azure Key Vault Access on VM throws OAuth Exception: The ClientId option must be provided

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core-mvc, azure-keyvault

I'm trying to add Azure Key Vault access to my .Net Core app running on a VM in Azure. I feel like this should be a simple scenario, but I'm running in to trouble when the app starts up. It seems like something isn't configured correctly or maybe that I'm using the wrong dependencies.

The VM is running in Azure with a system assigned managed identity and it has get/list access to the key vault. The app is a .Net core 3 MVC app and I'm trying to load configurations from the key vault.

When the app starts up, a series of three Errors show up in the Application Window Logs. They all look like:

`System.ArgumentException: The 'ClientId' option must be provided. (Parameter 'ClientId')

at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OAuth.OAuthOptions.Validate()

at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.RemoteAuthenticationOptions.Validate(String scheme)

at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationBuilder.<>c__DisplayClass4_0'2.<AddSchemeHelper>b__1(TOptions o)`

I've tried a few different things in the code, but I still get the same errors. This is in the Program.cs file and I've removed the environment checks for brevity.

```
      public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureAppConfiguration((context, config) =>
            {
                    var builtConfig = config.Build();
                    var azureServiceTokenProvider = new AzureServiceTokenProvider();
                    var keyVaultClient = new KeyVaultClient(
                        new KeyVaultClient.AuthenticationCallback(
                            azureServiceTokenProvider.KeyVaultTokenCallback));

                    config.AddAzureKeyVault(
                        $"https://{builtConfig[keyVaultEnvironmentConfigName]}.vault.azure.net/",
                        keyVaultClient,
                        new DefaultKeyVaultSecretManager());
            })
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
            {
                webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
            });
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what my issue was. The key vault access was actually working, but the configurations weren't accessible in the Startup.cs file. I had several OAuth providers setup in the Startup.cs file and the first one being configured was setting a ClientId. That is the reason I was getting my particular error.

I'm attaching my Startup function and the changes I needed to make for everything to work. I noticed that I have to have the Azure Key Vault configuration in both the Program.cs file and in the Startup.cs file or else different things wouldn't work at different points in the app.

Original Startup.Startup function. Maybe there is an issue here that keeps the Key Vault values from being accessible?

```
public Startup(IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
            .AddJsonFile("devsecrets.json", optional: true)
            .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true)
            .AddEnvironmentVariables();

        Configuration = builder.Build();
     }
```

Fixed Startup.Startup function:

```
public Startup(IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
            .AddJsonFile("devsecrets.json", optional: true)
            .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true)
            .AddEnvironmentVariables();

        Configuration = builder.Build();

        // logic to set useKeyVault has been omitted
        if (useKeyVault)
        {
            var azureServiceTokenProvider = new AzureServiceTokenProvider();
            var keyVaultClient = new KeyVaultClient(
                new KeyVaultClient.AuthenticationCallback(
                    azureServiceTokenProvider.KeyVaultTokenCallback));

            builder.AddAzureKeyVault(
                $"https://{Configuration[keyVaultEnvironmentConfigName]}.vault.azure.net/",
                keyVaultClient,
                new DefaultKeyVaultSecretManager());

            Configuration = builder.Build();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There could be 2 things gone wrong.

1. One is in your appsetting.json or appsetting.production.json (if you are overriding) should have right value as mentioned below
   {
   "keyVaultEnvironmentConfigName": "your Key Vault Name"
   }
   Note: If you are running locally it wont be working unless you have registered in AD for localhost url. Because in Azure portal you have configured for WebAPP url so running locally will not work for the same clientid.
2. If above configuration key name and value is correct then Managed Identity is not configured correctly.

Note: As mentioned above if you are running on local environment ensure localhost url is added in Azure AD or bypass KeyVault in DevMode.

Comment: 1) I checked the appsettings.json file and that is returning the correct key vault name.

2) For the Managed Identity, I went to the VM in Azure -> Identity -> System Assigned -> Status: On. And in the Key Vault -> Access policies -> Add Access Policy -> Selected principal: the name of the VM. I also gave the VM Get/List permissions to the secrets.

Answer (score 0):

Does the Service Principal have access to Azure Key Vault? While  creating service principal you also need to create Client Secrets which you can create from Azure AD Application. This Client secret is used for the authentication purpose.